# Reading the content of a SPAN in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mouseevent

How could I create a `.click()` function that if the text of the span is "Option1", it will give me the ability to make some action (for instance `alert('you selected option1');`).

```html
<ul class="tabs" style="height: 27px;">
  <li class="tabs-selected"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option1</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option2</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option3</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I'd recommend using something like a class or data-attribute, rather than the element text, as the text is likelier to change. So with @BelgianMyWaffle's code, you could replace `$(this).text()` with data like this: `$(this).data('option') === 1` and have this as html `<li data-option="1"></li>` [data-attribute demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mm2tgbtc/1/) **or** with class: `$(this).hasClass('option1')` with html `<li class="option1"></li>`. [class demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lollero/mm2tgbtc/2/)

Comment: @Joonas I know I could do so but I am limited to the code generator which is a framework ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
        alert("You selected: " + $(this).text());
    });
});
```

Comment: Very fine Belgian. But I need to make operations on them separately. What would it look like then I would like to handle only 1 specified selection like If this.text == "li.text { actions for single select }  <- pseduocode

Comment: Instead of the alert, just use: `if($(this).text() == "Option1")` do something specific.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("ul").on("click", "li", function() {
        alert("You selected: " + $(this).text());
        if ($(this).text() == "Option1"){
            alert('Option one is selected');
        }

    });
```

Full code thanks Belgian

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it like this.

```js
$("ul li").click(function() {
  alert("You selected: " + $(this).text());
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tabs" style="height: 27px;">
  <li class="tabs-selected"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option1</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option2</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="tabs-inner" style="width: 112px; height: 27px; line-height: 25px;"><span class="tabs-title">Option3</span><span class="tabs-icon"></span></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```